# I do not want to invite my PhD advisor to my commencement ceremony

Tags: advisor, united-states

I really do not want to invite PhD advisor to my commencement ceremony and would like to invite another senior professor from my committee. How to go about doing this? In the future, I plan to block him from everywhere and will have no contact with him at all.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Note that we generally require a professional tone, so I removed your last sentence. Please check out our [help] for more info.

Comment: By "invite" are you asking about inviting their attendance only, or are you asking about inviting their participation, as in "hooding" or such. If the latter, I'll need to radically revise my answer.

Comment: I was talking about hooding ceremony @Buffy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I first answered this, my assumption was that the invitation was only for attendance, not for an essential part of the ceremony. I'd guess that you don't have a lot of choice in who will do the hooding and inviting someone else to do it could easily be considered an insult.

You might have to just "grin and bear it" knowing that the future will be freer. I once had to literally kiss the ring of someone I despised. I lived through the experience.

On the other hand, it might be possible to avoid the situation by not attending the ceremony at all. I didn't attend mine, making my mother very unhappy. But rules differ and it isn't possible to do this everywhere.

But given the change in meaning, look carefully at [the answer of StephenG - Help Ukraine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/183638/75368) who makes some good points.

<strike>Actually, there is no reason to invite him. He may go for other reasons, perhaps, but there is no need for an invitation.</strike>

Some faculty go to commencement and it can be quite a show, but others avoid it entirely when possible.

This may be a very local cultural thing, but I've never actually heard of it before, especially in the US.

Comment: Does your university not have the tradition of hooding PhD recipients??

Comment: @Dawn, it needn't be by the advisor. Chairs and Deans can do that. And it might just be an aide. The Dean, perhaps, delivers a diploma.

Comment: In many cases, the advisor will be asked, by default, to do the hooding.

Comment: The hooding needn’t be by the advisor, but it often is by default, so I was surprised to see you say in the answer that you had never heard of such a thing.

Comment: Surprised you stuck it out with him. But it's your call, I suppose. *Buona fortuna*.

Comment: @Buffy I am considering not going to the ceremony as well. My mother will be super mad as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest a couple of reasons to consider a more constructive approach.  PhDs are stressful and maybe the anger you feel now will, in time, seem less of an issue.  Keep an open mind.

**Could be an opportunity to heal things.**

As you cannot control whether the person comes to the ceremony or not, you may as well try and make the most of it.  Academia, like any other career, tends to go smoother when you make friends and if you can't make friends, at least don't leave a lot of enemies in your wake.

This is just one more step and you may never have to have direct dealings with them again.  Instead of parting on bad terms I'd suggest just going with the flow (at worst) or (at best) trying to offer an olive branch - a skill it's useful to learn and practice in a career.

I would certainly not try blocking them in the future - that's unprofessional and unproductive.  Unless you are being abused by them there's no reason to do this and it looks bad.  I'd suggest the opposite approach if you can bring yourself to do it - inviting them to the ceremony.  Maybe things are too bitter between you to do that, but consider making a small effort to heal a rift.  Careers are worth investing in and this is a useful skill to develop.

Remember you really have no way of knowing if this person may yet prove a useful contact in the future.  It's just business.

**Potentially creating a problem for someone else.**

> would like to invite another senior professor from my committee

Do you have a particular reason for doing this ?  It may actually create problems for the other professor as they still have to co-exist with your disliked advisor.  You're putting the liked professor in an awkward position in terms of internal politics.  Maybe don't do this unless they made a critical contribution to your success or you're very friendly with them.

> How to go about doing this?

If you feel you really need to do this I'd suggest asking the disliked advisor if they would object to you inviting the other person.   Have a reason for this - e.g. you became friendly and would like to keep it going, or maybe the liked professor was especially helpful and you want to acknowledge it in some small way.

At the end of the day maybe even say thank you to your advisor.  You did, after all, survive the gruelling process and will be getting that covetted PhD - not everyone does.

Comment: Thanks @StephenG - Help Ukraine, needed to hear some positive outlook towards this.